# issue when upgrading to Cucumber-JVM 1.1.4

Tags: cucumber, cucumber-jvm, cucumber-junit

I have been using cucumber-java 1.1.1 and moving to 1.1.4.
But, when I run the tests from eclipse, I am getting the following error. I am not sure why.

please let me know how I can resolve this issue.

com.xyz.test.abc.testngintgn.CucumberTestImpl.cucumber failed
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a file or directory: /Users/me/git/qa_abcTestCases/cucumbertests/classpath:cucumber/runtime
    at cucumber.runtime.io.FileResourceIterator$FileIterator.(FileResourceIterator.java:54)
    at cucumber.runtime.io.FileResourceIterator.(FileResourceIterator.java:20)
    at cucumber.runtime.io.FileResourceIterable.iterator(FileResourceIterable.java:19)
    at cucumber.runtime.io.ResourceLoaderReflections.getDescendants(ResourceLoaderReflections.java:30)
    at cucumber.runtime.io.ResourceLoaderReflections.instantiateSubclasses(ResourceLoaderReflections.java:55)
    at cucumber.runtime.Runtime.loadBackends(Runtime.java:78)
    at cucumber.runtime.Runtime.(Runtime.java:52)
    at com.paypal.test.abc.testngintgn.CucumberTestImpl.cucumber(CucumberTestImpl.java:71)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:80)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:714)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:901)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1231)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:127)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:111)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)

Comment: Hi, I am having a similar problem. Did you find a solution?

Comment: No, but there is Cucumber with support for testNG available now in Cucumber 1.5. So, I was suggested to migrate to it instead.